# Does anyone know of a map of Solar PV Installers in Ireland?

Tags: solar-power

Just checking if there's anyone else in Ireland out there ?

I'll be using the SolarMeitheal tag to group all questions about domestic Solar PV in Ireland.

The [Meitheal](https://translate.google.com?sl=ga&tl=en&text=Meitheal&op=translate) idea is a workgroup or a peer-to-peer support network for questions about Solar PV in Ireland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it there is a map, but the official list of suppliers/installers is on the SEAI website
https://www.seai.ie/grants/find-a-registered-professional/solar-pv-companies/